# MySQL won't start on ubuntu 16.04 - apparmor="DENIED"

Tags: mysql

When tried to log in to the MySQL server yesterday I received the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

When I realised the server had been turned off I attempted to start it again and received the following error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Below is the response from **systemctl status mysql.service**:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since sáb 2019-01-05 11:53:11 CET; 3s ago
  Process: 24667 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 24653 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24667 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 24668 (mysql-systemd-s)
    Tasks: 2
   Memory: 1.5M
      CPU: 244ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─24668 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─24683 sleep 1

ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.441025Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.441108Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 200
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.612971Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.615321Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log) s
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.618519Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.err' for e
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.618658Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.618776Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24667]: 2019-01-05T10:53:11.618879Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
ene 05 11:53:11 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
lines 1-24/24 (END)
```

And the response from **journalctl -xe**:

```
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/24999/status" p
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/n
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/24999/status" p
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685682.938:11771): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685682.938:11772): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin
ene 05 11:54:42 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685682.938:11773): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 audit[24999]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:42.946027Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:42.946094Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 200
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:43.124809Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:43.127236Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log) s
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:43.130517Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.err' for e
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:43.130653Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:43.130771Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 mysqld[24999]: 2019-01-05T10:54:43.130875Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685683.126:11774): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbi
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685683.126:11775): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbi
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685683.126:11776): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbi
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685683.126:11777): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbi
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685683.126:11778): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbi
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1546685683.126:11779): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbi
ene 05 11:54:43 james-Aspire-E5-571 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
lines 1465-1506/1506 (END)
```

According to a help article I read this error is caused by Apparmor not being configured properly.

The article states that the resolution to this problem is to add permissions reported by the error message to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld file. In this situation, it is required to add r permissions to /proc/*/status and /sys/devices/system/node/.

However, when I tried to do this I found that I was unable to edit the file.

I have tried to remove mysql (purging is not an option as I need to protect my databases) in order to re-install but I am given the response that the mysql package could not be located...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "However, when I tried to do this I found that I was unable to edit the file." - were you using a root shell?

Answer (score 1):

Please check that the mysql user can read/write on the `/var/lib/mysql` directory.

That directory should actually be **owned** by the mysql user.

I had a similar issue and the log pointed to an apparmor related issue, but in reality my problem was the `/var/lib/mysql` directory and its contents owned by root after restoring the MySql data directory from a backup.